# How to make a new object from an old one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically my goal is to take an object with string values, translate the values and create a new object full of the translated strings. So lets say if I have:

```
const strings = {
    "name": "my name",
    "age": "my age"
}
```

and I would like to translate that so i have a new object such as:

```
const translated = {
    "name": "mi nombre",
    "age": "mi edad"
}
```

I have tried using the map function but havent really been able to get anything to work. Also I'm not sure how Id go about translating just the values of the object and not the labels. Anyone have any suggestions? I'm not worried about the logic of doing the translation, I'm using AWS translate, and that has to provide a string.

My current file:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import uuid from 'uuid';
const translate = new AWS.Translate({apiVersion: '2019-01-01'});
import * as dynamoDbLib from "./libs/dynamodb-lib";
import { success, failure } from "./libs/response-lib";


export async function main(event, context) {
  try {

    const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const toTranslate = {
        SourceLanguageCode: 'auto', /* required */
        TargetLanguageCode: data.TargetLanguageCode, /* required */
        Text: data.Text, /* required */
    };

    const translated = await translate.translateText(toTranslate).promise();

    console.log(translated);

    const params = {
        "TableName": "sites",
        "Item": {
            "userId": "1",
            "siteId": uuid.v1(),
            "Language": translated.TargetLanguageCode,
            "SiteName": translated.TranslatedText,
            "CreatedAt": Date.now()
        }
    }

    try {
        await dynamoDbLib.call("put", params);
        return success(params.Item);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        return failure({ status: false });
    }


  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } 
}
```

Attempt:

```
const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

    function translate(toTranslate) {
      const translated = await translate.translateText(toTranslate).promise();
    }

    const translated = {};
    const promises = Object.keys(data.Text).map(key =>
      translate(data.Text[key], data.TargetLanguageCode).then(translation =>
        translated[key] = translation
      )
    );
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => translationsAreReady(translated));
```

Comment: if you want the whole UI translation go for https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next  or any other internationalization library

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I was checking that out but unfortunately it has to be done with AWS translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const translated = {};
Object.keys(strings).forEach(key => {
  translated[key] = translate_sync(strings[key], lang);
});
```

However, a synchronous `translate` is probably not available, so...

```
const translated = {};
const promises = Object.keys(strings).map(key =>
  translate_promise(strings[key], lang).then(translation =>
    translated[key] = translation
  )
);
Promise.all(promises).then(() => translationsAreReady(translated));
```

Comment: This seems to make sense but I'm trying to work out how to implement it into my current set up, I have put my full code so far into the question

Comment: I added the general case for async handling; I can see you already know how to make a translation promise, and it should also be easy to move anything that requires the translations into a separate function (`translationsAreReady`).

Comment: Almost (unless I'm missing something); `translate` needs to return the promise for it to work, so don't `await` it (and `await` can't work unless in `async` function anyway). Just do `return translate.translateText(toTranslate).promise();`

Comment: So when I run it, I'm getting the error `translate.translateText is not a function`

Comment: Ah. You made your own function `translate` which overwrote the AWS `translate`. Rename the function to something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193315/discussion-between-tierno-and-amadan).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `translate(term: String, lang: String)` would be you translation function, here's how you would map:

```
const strings = {
    "name": "my name",
    "age": "my age"
}

let lang = "es";

const translated = {...strings};
for (const key in translated) {
  translated[key] = translate(translated[key], lang);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved via `Object.entries()` and `Array.reduce()` as shown below. Also note the use of `Promise.all()` which is used to resolve multile calls to the asynchronous function `translate.translateText()` into an array of `translatedEntries` from which the new `translated` is constructed:

```js
/* Input object */
const strings = {
  "name": "my name",
  "age": "my age"
}

/* A mock of your translation function/library */
const translate = {
  translateText: async(value) => {
    if (value === 'my name') return "mi nombre";
    if (value === 'my age') return "mi edad";
    return "?"
  }
}

Promise.all(Object.entries(strings).map(async([key, value]) => {

  /* Map all entries to a promise that resolves each translation request
  asynchronously */
  const translation = await translate.translateText(value);

  /* Map translation result for this entry */
  return [key, translation];

})).then((translatedEntries) => {
  
  /* Construct a new object from key/value pairs in translated entries */
  return translatedEntries.reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
    return { ...result,
      [key]: value
    }
  }, {})

}).then((translated) => {
  
  console.log(translated);
});
```

Comment: It has to be dynamic, so the function can't know what is in the `strings` object. It has to work with what its given

Comment: @TiernO just updated answer with a bit more detail - hope that helps!